# jquery ajax() back button wont change content

Tags: jquery

i made simple $.ajax() with hashchange with local files, however the back button only changes url, not the content. Nothing i found seems to be working for me. COuld anybody help me?

```js
  $(document).on('click', ".nextPage2", () => {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'page2.html',
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(result) {
        $('.content').html(result);
      }
    });
    window.location.hash = 'looks';
    return false;



  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="content"></div>



    <button type="button" class="nextPage2" name="button">page2</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the URL, you are also using JavaScript to modify the DOM.

You need to [listen for changes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) to the URL and use JavaScript to modify the DOM *again*.

```
function navigated() {
    if (location.hash === '#something-different') {
        $('.content').html("The content for something-different");
    }
}

window.addEventListener("hashchange", navigated);
```

Comment: If i add "page1.html" into .html it displays this as string instead of content//html

Comment: nvm... changed .html to .load and it works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: If you refresh the page then you aren't *changing* the hash. Write an event handler for the `load` event too.

Comment: you mean $(".content").on("load", function() { ?

Comment: The load event (or the document read event) for the document you are refreshing. `addEventListener('load', handler)`

Answer (score 0):

If page2.html is an Html file, than use .load() function instead .html()

```
$('.content').load(result);
```

load() will load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.
http://api.jquery.com/load/

code in page2.html mustn't have "html", "head" and "body" tags, cause will be inserted inside your .content div

Hope this Help

**Hele**